# Android: Including Separate Library Project (eg Facebook SDK)

Tags: android, facebook

I have added the facebook SDK to my workspace and added it to the libraries in my apps' project properties.
I noticed that if the facebook SDK project is not open when I try to build my apps, the build fails as the facebook project also needs to be open.
I'm just wondering if I have to copy the facebook sdk to my projects folders before releasing it or does eclipse automatically build this into the apps APK file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just create new project from a file where Facebook-sdk is. Then go right click on your project -->Properties --> Android and then in a Library section click Add and select Facebook SDK. You don't have to copy Facebook-sdk to your project, eclipse would do that job for you.